# Cannot Bootstrap chef (10.8) on new EC2 Instance - net-ssh conflict

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, chef-infra

I have found [Can't install chef, gem version conflict with net-ssh net-ssh-multi net-ssh-gateway](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14738091/cant-install-chef-gem-version-conflict-with-net-ssh-net-ssh-multi-net-ssh-gate/14738173#14738173) in my research, but unfortunately none of those workarounds work for me in my particular case.

I'm trying to bootstrap chef on an EC2 instance.

I cannot upgrade to 11.x.

This one does not work: (added command I run to install chef which includes --verbose and --version)

```
gem install net-ssh -v 2.2.2 --no-ri --no-rdoc
gem install net-ssh-gateway -v 1.1.0 --no-ri --no-rdoc --ignore-dependencies
gem install net-ssh-multi -v 1.1.0 --no-ri --no-rdoc --ignore-dependencies
gem install chef --no-ri --no-rdoc --verbose --version 0.10.8
```

Is there any way to work around this problem without upgrading chef?

I've also tried the above but with

```
gem install chef --pre --no-ri --no-rdoc
```

and that fails too. These are both workarounds outlined in the linked post above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does [this](http://jtimberman.housepub.org/blog/2013/02/06/chef-and-net-ssh-dependency-broken/) blog post by Joshua Timberman help?

Comment: Thanks! Yea, I found that too with the help of a co-worker yesterday. It tells me i pretty much have to upgrade from 10.8 to at least 10.20 which it a bit better than 10.8 to 11.2.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered these issues running a 0.10.4 Chef Server and equivalent Chef Clients when using Knife EC2 tool to launch servers.

For anyone else like me who had issues getting KNIFE to launch an instance without this net-ssh issue, placing the following in my bootstrap file didn't work as per recommendations elsewhere on SO:

```
gem install chef --no-ri --nordoc --verbose --version 0.10.24
```

The way that worked was to use a flag on the knife ec2 command:

```
--bootstrap-version 10.24.0
```

The version can be higher than 10.20.0.